# MSG Google Calendar adding a Feed

Tags: html, calendar, icalendar, google-gadget

I know I must be brain-dead, and I had a solution about a month ago, but accidentally deleted it (oops)!

From the [this page](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/calendar3.xml&up_calendarFeeds=&up_calendarColors=&up_firstDay=0&up_dateFormat=0&up_timeFormat=1:00pm&up_showDatepicker=1&up_hideAgenda=0&up_showEmptyDays=0&up_showExpiredEvents=1&synd=open&w=320&h=165&title=__MSG_Google_Calendar__&lang=en&country=ALL&border=#ffffff%7C3px,1px%20solid%20#999999) you can create a small widget calendar. With the date picker AND agenda (yes both are needed)

It produces some code like so:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/calendar3.xml&amp;up_calendarFeeds=&amp;up_calendarColors=&amp;up_firstDay=0&amp;up_dateFormat=0&amp;up_timeFormat=1%3A00pm&amp;up_showDatepicker=1&amp;up_hideAgenda=0&amp;up_showEmptyDays=0&amp;up_showExpiredEvents=1&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=165&amp;title=__MSG_Google_Calendar__&amp;lang=en&amp;country=ALL&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

However it doesn't specify the calendar, and always loads the local calendar. I see there is the variable `up_calendarFeeds` in there, and that got me thinking I should try to add a feed. I searched and found [google's page](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) on feeds. The says the feed url is in the format of:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/userID/private-magicCookie/full
```

`full` over `basic` is for machine readable, of which I assume the gadget uses. However when I set the `up_calenderFeeds` variable with my data, It loads nothing. What am I missing? This being my final code:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/calendar3.xml&amp;up_calendarFeeds=https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ohmusama@gmail.com/private-0b7544f4b5f2198fc76c96e59f285dad/full&amp;up_calendarColors=&amp;up_firstDay=0&amp;up_dateFormat=0&amp;up_timeFormat=1%3A00pm&amp;up_showDatepicker=1&amp;up_hideAgenda=0&amp;up_showEmptyDays=0&amp;up_showExpiredEvents=1&amp;synd=open&amp;w=195&amp;h=500&amp;title=Portland+IPA+Calendar&amp;lang=en&amp;country=ALL&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C0px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure If I should be using the private key or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, since no one was able to help me. I searched and searched and found some answers.

There are a variety of different variables in the get string with many characters that need escaping. First for what ever reason, `up_calendarFeeds` must be set to `({})` which url encoded ends up being `up_calendarFeeds=%28%7B%7D%29`

Then you need to set 2 variables for your calendar to work properly (I think you need both), `up_c0u` and `up_c0c` both to your feed path. Note that It seems this can be in an array form, so you can add many feeds by incrementing 0, so `up_c1u` `up_c2u` `up_c3u` etc